# Two multidimensional array in Foreach

Tags: php

I want to work with both array simultaneously
you will understand what i want just check foreach loop

```
<?php
$ar = array("az"=>"1");
$ar2 = array("az2"=>"2");
*foreach ($ar as $key => $value and $ar2 as $key2 => $value2) {
    echo $key2 ."<br>".$key;
}
die();
?>
```

Comment: user for loop instead of foreach

Comment: size of both array are same or not

Comment: if size of both array same go with for loop and work with index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (array_combine(array_keys($ar), array_keys($ar2)) as $key => $key2) {
   echo $key, ', ', $key2, '<br>';
   echo $ar[$key], ', ', $ar2[$key2], '<br>';
}
```

This strictly requires that both arrays have the same number of elements.

Alternatively, if you want to *return* some new value instead of just echoing, I'd propose this:

```
$result = array_map(
    function ($key, $val, $key2, $val2) {
        return /* something like array("$key-$key2" => "$val-$val2") */;
    },
    array_keys($ar), $ar, array_keys($ar2), $ar2
);
```

For a more "bare metal" (and likely more efficient) solution, do:

```
reset($ar);
reset($ar2);

while (list($key, $val) = each($ar)) {
    list($key2, $val2) = each($ar2);

    echo $key, ', ', $key2, '<br>';
    echo $val, ', ', $val2, '<br>';
}
```

Comment: This is a nice clean solution!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution if your both array size is not same.
It will work for same size too

```
    $ar = array("az"=>"1","xy"=>"2");
    $ar2 = array("az2"=>"2","sa"=>4,"sds"=>5);
    $arkeys = array_keys($ar);
    $ar2keys=array_keys($ar2);

    for($i=0;$i<max(sizeof($ar),sizeof($ar2));$i++)
    {
        if(sizeof($ar)>$i)
        {
            echo $arkeys[$i];//key
            echo $ar[$arkeys[$i]];//value
        }
        if(sizeof($ar2)>$i)
        {
            echo $ar2keys[$i];//key
            echo $ar2[$ar2keys[$i]];//value
        }

    }
```